# Kirochoff's current law on Transmission line equation

Tags: transmission-line, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Kirochhof's current law]

In the figure above, for equation 2.1b i.e applying Kirchhoff's current law, why is not the resistance and inductance taken into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In equation (2.1b) all the terms are current.

There are 3 currents and there is no need to include resistance and inductance because the current through them is known i.e. i(z,t)